# Attach document to an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

Is it possible to attach a document to an email without saving it on the server?

The code below is something that attaches only after saving to the server. What I am looking for is to attach the document to the email without having it saved first instead just attach to the email from the path provided.

This is in Visual Studio 2005 using c#

```
if (SaveDocument.HasFile)
        {
            /* Get a reference to PostedFile object */               
            string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(SaveDocument.PostedFile.FileName);
                /* Save the file on the server */
            SaveDocument.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(strFileName));
                /* Create the email attachment with the uploaded file */
            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Server.MapPath(strFileName));
                /* Attach the newly created email attachment */
            message.Attachments.Add(attach);                  

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, there's [a constructor overload for `Attachment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab7hb4y5.aspx) which accepts a `Stream` instead of a file name.  So, for example, if you have a `byte[]` of data, you can create an `Attachment` from it:

```
var contentType new ContentType(MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
var attach = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(data), contentType);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use the constructor that takes a stream rather than a filename.

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab7hb4y5(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `PostedFile`'s `InputStream` directly to the `Attachment`.

```
if (SaveDocument.HasFile)
{
        /* Create the email attachment with the uploaded file */
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment attach = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(SaveDocument.PostedFile.InputStream, "filename");
        /* Attach the newly created email attachment */
    message.Attachments.Add(attach);                  

}
```

I haven't tried it yet, but it should work.